# Redirecting to a page from a form django

Tags: django

I need to direct to a blank html page(test_page1.html) on submition of my html form..How can I do it in Django?

I don't have any mapping for the new page in my urls.py file.

```
test_page.html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
This is a test page
{% if display_form %}
    <form action="test_page1.html" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        FIRST NAME : <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="register"/>
    </form>
{% else %}
    {% autoescape off %}
    {{ firstname }}
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>

views.py
def test_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'request.post = ', request.POST['fname']
        fname = cgi.escape(request.POST['fname'])
        print 'fname =', fname
        variables = RequestContext(request,{'display_form':False,'firstname':fname})
        return render_to_response('test_page.html',variables)
    else:
        variables = RequestContext(request,{'display_form':True})
        return render_to_response('test_page.html',variables)
```

Comment: Same way you do it with a link, use the target attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is an example right in the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

You need a redirect response instead of render_to_response:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

The post part of your function should look something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Your custom processing.
    if everything_is_alright:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/the_blank_page/')
    # Not everything is right, so re-render the original page with the form.
    # Put your custom render_to_response() stuff here.
```

Note that you might benefit by using Django's actual form mechanism. Django does all that `cgi.escape` stuff for you **plus** lots of extra safety features.